# Hide/show elements with same class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have some text toggle on click of elements with same class. I have the text showing on click but when I click another element the text remains. How do I have it removed from others when another element of same class is clicked?

```js
$('.video-carousel--thumbnail').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.now-playing').not(this).css('display', 'none');
  $(this).find('.now-playing').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
.now-playing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-carousel--thumbnail">
  <div class="l-thumbnail__title">
    <p><strong>Thumbnail One</strong></p>
    <p class="now-playing"><strong>Now Playing</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-carousel--thumbnail">
  <div class="l-thumbnail__title">
    <p><strong>Thumbnail Two</strong></p>
    <p class="now-playing"><strong>Now Playing</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-carousel--thumbnail">
  <div class="l-thumbnail__title">
    <p><strong>Thumbnail Three</strong></p>
    <p class="now-playing"><strong>Now Playing</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the DOM traversal logic when hiding all other elements. Just select them directly using `$('.now-playing')`. Also note that you can use `hide()` and `show()` instead of `css()`.

```
$('.video-carousel--thumbnail').on('click', function() {
  $('.now-playing').hide()
  $(this).find('.now-playing').show();
});
```

Also note that if you want to toggle the elements then your `not()` selector is incorrect as `this` refers to the `.video-carousel--thumbnail` element which raised the event, not the `.now-playing` element to exclude from the collection.

For that to work you need to find the relevant element first, then exclude it from those you remove the class from before calling `toggle()`. Try this:

```js
$('.video-carousel--thumbnail').on('click', function() {
  var $target = $(this).find('.now-playing');
  $('.now-playing').not($target).hide()
  $target.toggle();
});
```

```css
.now-playing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-carousel--thumbnail">
  <div class="l-thumbnail__title">
    <p><strong>Thumbnail One</strong></p>
    <p class="now-playing"><strong>Now Playing</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-carousel--thumbnail">
  <div class="l-thumbnail__title">
    <p><strong>Thumbnail Two</strong></p>
    <p class="now-playing"><strong>Now Playing</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-carousel--thumbnail">
  <div class="l-thumbnail__title">
    <p><strong>Thumbnail Three</strong></p>
    <p class="now-playing"><strong>Now Playing</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to tell about the toggle() also... 
This shows/hides the text with 1 function

Comment: True, that's an option, but depends on how the OP wants each element to behave on subsequent click

Comment: His first line of his question says toggle :P .. But i know that it depends on wanted behavior